# Login concept in xamarin forms

Tags: asp.net, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for a login functionality in my xamarin forms application. where the user can login at once and I can maintain his id throughout the app even if the app is closed. I have a webapi with login method, I can authenticate the user with checking the username and password but my next task is to keep this userid throughout the app.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need authentication functionality in xamarin forms app.

Comment: "I need" is not a question.  Please read "How to Ask" in the help section before posting.  What you've posted is a broad, vague requirement without any technical detail or obvious attempts at research.  Do you need help creating the login UI?  Or do you not understand how to call your WebAPI from a mobile app?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: I did my research but I'm confused. I need help in creating authentication and authorization in xamarin forms app. I can able to call webAPI and authenticate the username and password but how do I maintain this ID in my entire app?

Comment: That is a much better question than what you originally posted.  Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android

Comment: so when a user logs In I need to save the value to the storage and when he opens the app I need to check the stored value?

Comment: yes, something like that